# Accepting two models as action method parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model, controller

I'm developing a site in MVC, and I have a payment form which includes customer information as well as payment information. I'm not storing payment info in my database, so I don't want to add any of it to my customer info model. It'd be nice if I could do something like this:

```
public void PaymentConfirmation(CustomerInfo customer, PaymentInfo payment)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

But I don't think the mvc model binder does anything like that by default. What's the best practice for handling situations like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that when you say

> I'm not storing payment info in my database, so I don't want to add
>   any of it to my customer info model.

What you mean is that your customer model is a domain model (generated from EF or some other ORM).  If not using an ORM, the single responsibility principle still comes into play in that `PaymentInfo` is really not related to the `CustomerInfo` and should have its own base class.  Not combining these into a big "do everything" class makes sense.

What you can do, however, is create a ViewModel for this particular view that contains all of the information that you need.  This will not cause a DB change and is, basically, a simple wrapper for all the data that is needed by the view to do whatever it does.  A basic example would be

```
public class PaymentConfirmationViewModel{

    public CustomerInfo Customer {get;set;}

    public PaymentInfo Payment {get;set;}

}
```

As you can see, we are wrapping two stand alone classes into one for consumption by the view/action result.  However, using View Models allows you to completely customize and restrict/add the information that is available to your view.  Meaning, if there are properties on the domain model that the view does not need, then don't make them part of the view model.

Now, your controller method would be

```
public void PaymentConfirmation(PaymentConfirmationViewModel model)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

The only other item you would need to change is your view, in that your Html Helpers would need a slightly different lambda expression (random example).

```
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.FirstName)
```

would become

```
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Customer.FirstName)
```

If you are manually creating your input fields in raw HTML, the the following updates would occur.

```
<input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" />
```

would become (note the underscore in the **ID** attribute of the input field)

```
<input type="text" id="Customer_FirstName" name="Customer.FirstName" />
```

Comment: I'm using a derivative of data mapper pattern -- no orm. I really just meant that I don't want to have one model that has two separate concerns: storage and payment. It'd feel a little like a god object I guess.

Comment: I am not sure the 'God Object' applies here.  This class is only a collection of properties with their data annotations, constructors, etc stored in their actual files.  Basically, we are creating a wrapper object to contain all the data we need for a single view, which is typical in an MVC project.  Since these properties are extremely easily separated from the view model class, you can pass those properties on to whatever business logic you need individually.  Eg `PaymentService.ProcessPayment(model.PaymentInfo)` and `CustomerService.UpdateCustomer(model.CustomerInfo)`

Comment: I've tried to stay away from viewmodels, for the most part. Maybe I shouldn't be, though. So if I combine those two in a ViewModel, I'm assuming my view would contain stuff like <input type="text" name="Customer.Address" /> ? I'm staying away with mvc helpers in case I ever feel like making this a node.js app -- for portability's sake.

Comment: I wasn't saying what you were suggesting was a god object, I was saying that adding properties to my CustomerInfo model would make CustomerInfo kind of a god object, hence why I'm here. Your method looks fine.

Comment: Though I haven't used node, I don't see how using the helpers would prevent you from using it.  They render extremely clean HTML and you can extend your HTML properties using the lambda expressions.  The Id/Name elements are the name of the property, so `@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.CustomerInfo.Name)` would render `<input type="text" id="CustomerInfo.Name" name="CustomerInfo.Name" />`

Comment: I know -- I meant in terms of copying the code over. I don't wanna have to go through and get the rendered html for each page in that scenario -- I'd rather dump everything from my Views folder into a node project, take a few directives out, and be good to go.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - oh, in that case, yes you are 100%.  The `PaymentInfo` is most likely almost completely unrelated to the `CustomerInfo` object and thus should have its own base class.  I see where you are coming from now.  And as a corallary to my previous comment, your method is completely fine and I think you are correct in the Id/Name attributes of manually constructed inputs.

Comment: Cool, thanks. If you want to compile all of these comments into a reasonable answer for future viewers, I'll upvote/accept it.

Comment: By the way, you should learn node. It's the language of the future. I was a huge c#/.NET pusher for years until I started working with node. Now all I really build in .NET is enterprise-y stuff.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - updated and think I captured the essence of the comment thread.  Also, yeah, was just exposed to it a few weeks ago at a conference at an Azure/Node session.  Definitely looks pretty slick, but getting free time to "play" with new frameworks is a tad limited at the moment.  But, its on my list!

Comment: Oh I don't know why I was thinking you hadn't already posted an answer. I was spaced off and thinking that this discussion was just on the question itself. +1 and accepted regardless.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - quick edit, when using nested classes in a VM, the id attribute has an underscore and not a dot.  So `<input id="Customer_Address" name="Customer.Address"`  Just verified on a quicky project in VS

Comment: What role does the id play exactly, other than being a handle client side?

Comment: I think that's about it - the model binder/FormsCollection uses the name attribute.  However (would need to verify), I think model binding breaks if the id attribute is not present.  Never dug any deeper than that, just remember it causing me issues in the past (and possibly could have been something else).

Comment: Nah, I never use ids unless I need a handle to do something in javascript. Cool, just making sure I wasn't missing something